# NSString Split String Based on Numeric values

Tags: ios, objective-c, split, nsstring, substring

I was hoping to get some assistance with splitting one of my NSString values. Consider the following below:

```
NSString *string = @"_o_t_d_n__";
```

Basically, I would like to segment this `NSString *string` above into 3 separate string values, based on the numeric delimiters below which are stored in an NSArray:

```
NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @3, @2, @5];
```

Which would then result in the following, based on those delimiter values:

```
3 = @"_o_"
2 = @"t_"
6 = @"d_n__"
```

What would be the best approach by looping through this array segmenting the string based of the numeric values contained within the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSArray *array = @[@(3),@(2),@(5)];
NSUInteger loc = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    NSUInteger len = [[array objectAtIndex:i] unsignedIntegerValue];
    NSString *subStr = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(loc, len)];
    loc += len;
}
```

If you want to loop through the NSString, make a char pointer, which is slightly faster than the first method.

```
NSString *string = @"_o_t_d_n__";
const char *c = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
char *myData = calloc(3, 1);
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < [string length]; i++, j++) {
    myData[j] = c[i];
    if (i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 9) {
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:myData length:sizeof(myData) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
        if (i == 2) myData = realloc(myData, 2);
        if (i == 4) myData = realloc(myData, 5);
        j = -1;
    }
}
free(myData);
```

Comment: Thanks. Sure does make this clearer for me. Could I possibly do this somehow through a loop?

Comment: Spot on mate. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use regex to do it. Here's how i would do it:

```
 let string = "_o_t_d_n__"
 let first = 3
 let second = 2
 let third = 5
 let expression = NSRegularExpression.regularExpressionWithPattern("([a-z]{\(first)})([a-z]{\(second)})([a-z]{\(third),})", options: nil, error: nil)
 let range = NSMakeRange(0, string.length)
 expression.enumerateMatchesInString(string, options: nil, range: range, usingBlock:{ (result, MatchingFlags, unsafePointer) in
         let firstResult = string.substringWithRange(result.rangeAtIndex(1))
         let secondResult = string.substringWithRange(result.rangeAtIndex(2))
         let thirdResult = string.substringWithRange(result.rangeAtIndex(3))
 })
```

Additional validation checks are required, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: By the way, this is SWIFT code. Objective-c is kind of the same.